Upper bound for combinatorial sum
I'm looking for an asymptotic form for the following sum,
$$
S = \sum_{p=0}^k {n \choose p} 2^p
$$
The regime of interest for me is when $k = O(\sqrt{n})$ but a generalized result shouldn't be too hard. I'm able to understand for a given $p$ that
$$
{n \choose p} 2^p \leq (2ne/p)^p
$$
but not sure what to do from here. It seems like there should be a nice integral upper bound that I'm missing.

Note that when $p \le k < \tfrac{n}{2}-1$, we have:
$$\dbinom{n}{p-1}2^{p-1} = \dfrac{p}{2(n-p+1)} \cdot \dbinom{n}{p}2^{p} \le \dfrac{p}{n} \cdot \dbinom{n}{p}2^{p} < \dbinom{n}{p}2^{p}.$$
Hence, $$\dbinom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1} \le \dfrac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}2^k,$$ and $$\dbinom{n}{k-2}2^{k-2} \le \dfrac{k-1}{n}\dbinom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1} \le \dfrac{k-1}{n}\dfrac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k} \le \dfrac{k^2}{n^2}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k},$$ and for $p = 0,\ldots,k-2$, we have $$\dbinom{n}{p}2^p \le \dbinom{n}{k-2}2^{k-2} \le \dfrac{k^2}{n^2}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k}.$$
Therefore, $$\begin{align}\sum_{p = 0}^{k}\dbinom{n}{p}2^p &= \dbinom{n}{k}2^k + \dbinom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1} + \sum_{p = 0}^{k-2}\dbinom{n}{p}2^p \\ &\le \dbinom{n}{k}2^k + \dbinom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1} + \sum_{p = 0}^{k-2}\dbinom{n}{k-2}2^{k-2} \\ &= \dbinom{n}{k}2^k + \dbinom{n}{k-1}2^{k-1} + (k-1)\dbinom{n}{k-2}2^{k-2} \\ &\le \dbinom{n}{k}2^k + \dfrac{k}{n}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k} + \dfrac{k^3}{n^2}\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k} \\ &= \left(1 + \dfrac{k}{n} + \dfrac{k^3}{n^2}\right)\dbinom{n}{k}2^{k}.\end{align}$$ Therefore, if $k = o(n^{2/3})$, the sum is dominated by the last term, i.e., $$\sum_{p = 0}^{k}\dbinom{n}{p}2^p = (1+o(1))\dbinom{n}{k}2^k,$$ and the asymptotic you have for that should be good.
